# RegEx: Match all subcategories of a Wikipedia category

Tags: regex

How do I match all subcategories of a Wikipedia category? Say we are trying to find the subcategory names for the following category page on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Operation_Overlord

I have:

```
(<li><a href)(="\/)(wiki\/).*(title)
```

But this is too messy and matches more than the subcategories.

Thanks.

Comment: Each subcategory is contained in a `<div class="CategoryTreeSection">` and a `<div class="CategoryTreeItem">`; just use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
href="\/wiki\/Category:(?<slug>.*?)".*?>(?<name>.*?)<\/a>
```

See [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB9xB4/2)